# GC not collecting unreferenced Context objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, garbage-collection

Using this context

```
public class Context : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    // For migration test
    public Context()
    { }


    public Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {}
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

I'm running this code

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once ReturnValueOfPureMethodIsNotUsed
        (new Context(connection)).Students.ToList();
    }
    GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();
    PrintUsedMemory();
}
```

It seems that the garbage collector cannot collect memory used by the EntityFramework. I also try to change the way I create the context specifing contextOwnConnection = true but nothing change.

Is there a way to release the memory without explicitly disposing the context? (The problem disposing the context is that there are some related processes that shares the same context so I don't know when I can dispose the context).

**EDIT**
I tryed to create a wrapper over the context with a full implementation of IDisposable (call Dispose also from the destructor) but the destructor is never called.

**EDIT2**
PrintUsedMemory is not really important because you can see that the memory is not released also using Task Manager or waiting for the OutOfMemoryException.
Anyway, here is the code

```
private static void PrintUsedMemory()
{
    long usedMemory = GetUsedMemory();

    Console.WriteLine("Used memory {0}", usedMemory);
}

private static long GetUsedMemory()
{
    Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    long usedMemory = proc.WorkingSet64;
    return usedMemory;
}
```

**EDIT 3**
I started making same tests with WeakReference as suggested by @Evk.

**First test** is with this code where I specify the connection (normal sql connection) during context creation.

```
DbConnection connection = GetConnection();
connection.Open();

// create list of references
var errors = (new Context(connection)).Students.ToList();
var refs = errors.Select(c => new WeakReference(c)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("refs count = {0}", refs.Count);
// collect
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
Console.WriteLine(refs.All(c => !c.IsAlive) ? "all collected" : "something alive");
Console.WriteLine("done");
```

This is the output

```
refs count = 100
all collected
done
```

**Second test** I just inserted a for over the creation of references (this for my low knowledge of C# is a surprise)

```
DbConnection connection = GetConnection();
connection.Open();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // create list of references
    var errors = (new Context(connection)).Students.ToList();
    var refs = errors.Select(c => new WeakReference(c)).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("refs count = {0}", refs.Count);
    // collect
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine(refs.All(c => !c.IsAlive) ? "all collected" : "something alive");

}

Console.WriteLine("done");
```

This is the output

```
refs count = 100
something alive
refs count = 100
something alive
refs count = 100
something alive
refs count = 100
something alive
refs count = 100
something alive
done
```

The objects are not collected inside a for with a connection.

**Third test** I try the same code without specifing the connection

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    // create list of references
    var errors = (new Context()).Students.ToList();
    var refs = errors.Select(c => new WeakReference(c)).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("refs count = {0}", refs.Count);
    // collect
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine(refs.All(c => !c.IsAlive) ? "all collected" : "something alive");

}

Console.WriteLine("done");
```

This is the output

```
refs count = 100
all collected
refs count = 100
all collected
refs count = 100
all collected
refs count = 100
all collected
refs count = 100
all collected
done
```

The objects are collected inside a for without a connection.

For me is really strange

Comment: Better to not share a context so you can dispose it.  Limit it's lifetime to one atomic set of DB operations.

Comment: `DbContext` class holds internal finalizable object. Did you try the typical `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` before `PrintUsedMemory`?

Comment: Tryed just now (after your suggestion). Not working.

Comment: BTW, I inserted the finalizer and sometimes it is called but I don't understand when (if the context did not access to data?)

Comment: What is the expected result exactly? What should be collected, results of `ToList` call? Do you test without debugger and in release mode with optimizations enabled?

Comment: I'm expecting that the GC collects the result of ToList. I'm testing in release x86 with default (VS2013) optimizations.

Comment: First of all, don't ever use any shared object, if you are not sure then use some dependency injection. Also what does PrintUsedMemory print? Remember, .NET may have freed objects, but process will not free virtual memory it was allocated for .NET because .NET can reuse same memory.

Comment: @AkashKava I updated the question. And is late to avoid to use shared objects :-). About reusing memory I'm quite sure this is not my case. The memory is locked by the context (if I increase the number of cycles I receive OutOfMemoryException).

Comment: Its better to post full code by the way, you pass some connection which is not present in code. In such things every detail might be important. So, minimal reproducable complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if things will be collected in your example, but instead of using `PrintUsedMemory` (with the code you did not provide anyway), we will be using [WeakReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Documentation of this class `IsAlive` property:

> Gets an indication whether the object referenced by the current
>   WeakReference object has been garbage collected.

The code to test is simple (I use some test EF context I have here):

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var errors = (new TestDBEntities()).Errors.ToList();
        // create list of references
        var refs = errors.Select(c => new WeakReference(c)).ToList();
        // collect
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine(refs.All(c => !c.IsAlive) ? "all collected" : "something alive");
        Console.WriteLine("done");            
    }
}
```

If we compile that in release mode with optimizations and run without debugger attached - it will output "all collected", so all entities has been collected. Context was collected too, even though you did not dispose it explicitly - garbage collector called its finalizer and then collected it.

Now you are saying that you cannot properly dispose your context because you use it elsewhere. That is quite different from scenario you provided in your example, because that means you hold reference to the context elsewhere. Context in turn holds references to the object you received with your query. Let's modify example to reflect this:

```
class Program {
    // represents context reference you hold elsewhere
    static TestDBEntities _context = new TestDBEntities();
    public static void Main() {
        var errors = _context.Errors.ToList();
        // create list of references
        var refs = errors.Select(c => new WeakReference(c)).ToList();
        // collect
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine(refs.All(c => !c.IsAlive) ? "all collected" : "something alive");
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }                
}
```

Now it outputs "something alive", because indeed entities cannot be garbage collected - context holds references to them. What can be done? Use `AsNoTracking()` to prevent context to hold them:

```
class Program {
    // represents context reference you hold elsewhere
    static TestDBEntities _context = new TestDBEntities();
    public static void Main() {
        var errors = _context.Errors.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        // create list of references
        var refs = errors.Select(c => new WeakReference(c)).ToList();
        // collect
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine(refs.All(c => !c.IsAlive) ? "all collected" : "something alive");
        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }                
}
```

This example again outputs "all collected", because context does not longer holds references to entities (but of course you now cannot update\remove them with usual ways, without attaching them to context first).

And of course, as already repeated many times - do not ever reuse your context or store it globally. Create new context, do one logical operation you need, dispose it.

Comment: I can understand the problem in your code, you have a static context that you never release. The strange thing is that you have the same behaviour if you move the context inside Main and you set everything to null before executing `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` (and this is my issue). About using AsNoTracking it works but with the limitations you said (no update/delete).

Comment: I presented 3 scenarios, first is exactly code you presented in question. Second simulates scenatio when you hold context reference elsewhere, not necessary static (which is the case in your big application). There are no "problems" there. Is your scenario not represented in those 3?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first scenario (that is very similar to my case because I'm sure that in my real app I'm setting everything to null). Meanwhile I updated the question adding the PrintUsedMemory. I will check it using WeakReference to make a step forward understanding my issue (my real issue is that after few steps I receive an OutOfMemoryException).

Comment: I want to emphasise obce again that your real big application is similar to _second_ scenario, because you said you cannot dispose context because it is used in another place. This context will hold refefences to all entities ever queried with it and so can indeed cause out of memory over time.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer!!! Also in your case in some cases objects are not collected (specifyng connection during context creation and inside a loop - I'm not joking :) - ). If you are curious please see my EDIT 3 with your test.

Comment: @bubi you are welcome. As for the tests - it seems that in your case connection somehow holds reference to context (or any object inside it). When you run without for loop - both context and connection can be collected, they are not used anymore. However when you run in a loop - connection is needed for later loop iterations so cannot be collected. If it in turn has any reference to something inside context - it also cannot be collected, together with all entities. Might happen if your connection is EntityConnection for example (but you again didn't show what your connection is :)).

Answer (score 3):

DBContext implements IDisposable, so use that to release resources. Instead of:

```
(new Context(connection)).Students.ToList();
```

you can use:

```
Context ctx = new Context(connection);
ctx.Students.ToList();    
ctx.Dispose();
```

Or even better, use it with using statement, and share the same context in your loop:

```
using(Context ctx = new Context(connection))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once ReturnValueOfPureMethodIsNotUsed
            ctx.Students.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I wrote this is not an option. I'm sharing the context between processes (I'll never ever do it again) so I don't know when to dispose the context.

Comment: But you are creating a new context in every iteration. You don't even assign it to a variable, so you are not reusing it with other processes. And don't even hold a handle to it to dispose it later. You should definitely use using statement, and it will dispose it for you once you are out of scope.

Comment: This is just a sample code to reproduce my issue. I have this issue in a different bigger application.